# knockout computed not updating while change in view model being made from ajax

Tags: ajax, knockout.js

How much I know about knockout Js is that a computed gets updated anyhow depending on the viewmodel, but in my case its not happening. So basically I have a radio button which turns off and on and changes the date in the database, and the ajax calls returns and pushes the new date in the viewmodel so that the data changes.

So thats the summary. But the thing I want is that while the radio button is being updated I want a part of the html to change to active or disabled based on the radio button.

Firstly here is the HTML code.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <p>
    <span data-bind="text : $data.basketStatusValue"></span>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="on_off">
    <input type="checkbox"  data-bind="bootstrapSwitchOn: {
        tocall: $root.changeActiveBasketStatus
    }" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS code.

```
function MoneyInvestedViewModel(root /* root not needed */, money) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = money.ID;
    self.ORIG_ID = money.ORIG_ID;
    self.Available = money.Available;
    self.basketStatusValue = ko.computed (function () {
        if (self.Available == '9999-12-01') {
            return "Active";
        } else {
            return "Disabled";
        }
    });
};
```

And next is the code which is updating the view model moneyInvested . So the checkbox can show on or off.

```
self.changeActiveBasketStatus = function (bindingContext) {
    console.log(bindingContext);
    var Id = bindingContext.$data.ORIG_ID;
    var Available = bindingContext.$data.Available;
    if (Available == '9999-12-01') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/changeBasketStatus/' + auth + "/" + Id + "/" + 1,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        })
        .done(function (newAvailableDate) {
            bindingContext.$data.Available = newAvailableDate;
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.errorMessage(errorThrown);
        })
        .always(function (data){  
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/changeBasketStatus/' + auth + "/" + Id + "/" + 0,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        })
        .done(function (newAvailableDate) {
            bindingContext.$data.Available = newAvailableDate;
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.errorMessage(errorThrown);
        })
        .always(function (data) {
        });
    }
};
```

So basically the PROBLEM is that when all this update is done, the computed self.basketStatusValue does not get updated. So when I click the checkbox on, it doesnt show Active, or off for disabled, the checkbox is working perfectly, only the html `$data.basketStatusValue` is not updating through the computed function.

Just incase if necessary here is the code for the checkbox.

```
(function ($) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapSwitchOn = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            var tocall = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(options.tocall);

            $elem = $(element);
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch();
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', bindingContext.$data.Available === '9999-12-01' ? true : false); // Set intial state
            $elem.on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
                tocall(bindingContext);
                // valueAccessor()(data.value);
            });
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

To summarize, all I want to do is have the `$data.basketStatusValue` have "active" or "disabled" when the checkbox is on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty trick you can use to pull this off is empty the whole observable and push it with the new data. But honestly its not the right way to use it. I am assuming right now thats its a array, but you can remove observables too. Just put the observable name instead of YourArray().

```
self.refresh = function(){
        var data = YourArray().slice(0);
        YourArray.removeAll(); 
        self.YourArray(data);
        };
```

And place this function right after the done function

```
.done(function(newAvailableDate) {
   bindingContext.$data.Available = newAvailableDate;
  // here self.refresh();
 })
```

Comment: The lesson here is that you should not write answers with *"honestly its not the right way to use it"* in them. The OP will likely copy/paste your code and use it anyway - either because they did not bother reading the text you wrote, or because they don't care that it's wrong. Try not to set bad examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your binding handler is wrong, let's start with that.

It should:

- Set up Bootstrap switch on the element in `init()`
- React to change in `update()`
- Bind to an observabe (don't use a callback function). In our case the observable should contain the checkbox state, i.e. `true` or `false`.
- Properly dispose of the Bootstrap widget when the time comes.

So, this would work better:

```
(function ($) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapSwitch = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var options = valueAccessor();

            // set up bootstrap in init()
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch().on('switch-change', function (e, data) {
                options.value(data.value);
            });

            // see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-disposal.html
            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
                $(element).bootstrapSwitch("destroy");
            });
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var options = valueAccessor();

            // react to change in update()
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', options.value());
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Next we need to set up the viewmodel accordingly.

- `Available` needs to be observable. View changes depend on it.
- we need an observable that returns `true` or `false`, depending on `Available`
- we need an observable that returns `"Active"` or `"Disabled"`, depending on that
- we need a function that updates the server on change (through a subscription)

like this:

```
function MoneyInvestedViewModel(money) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = money.ID;
    self.ORIG_ID = money.ORIG_ID;
    self.Available = ko.observable(money.Available);
    self.errorMessage = ko.observable();

    self.BasketStatus = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.Available() == '9999-12-01';
    });
    self.BasketStatusText = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.basketStatus() ? "Active" : "Disabled";
    });

    // BEWARE: this is not actually correct (cicular dependency)
    self.BasketStatus.subscribe(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: BASEURL + 'index.php/moneyexchange/changeBasketStatus/' + auth + "/" + self.ID + "/" + 1,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        })
        .done(function (newAvailableDate) {
            self.Available(newAvailableDate);
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            self.errorMessage(errorThrown);
        });
    };
}
```

**Note:** Subscribe to the correct observable to update the server with the proper value. It was not clear from your question what value the server update depends on.

And now it's straightforward to bind a view to that:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <p><span data-bind="text: BasketStatusText"></span></p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="on_off">
    <input type="checkbox"  data-bind="bootstrapSwitch: {
        value: BasketStatus
    }" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it to me better, I appreciate it! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if(self.Available == '9999-12-01'){ return "Active"; }else{ return "Disabled";}
```

The trouble with this line is that it does not look up the value of any observable or computed, and thus it does not cause the computed to ever be updated.

You need to make self.Available *an observable* and then do `self.Available()`
This is how computeds work, they are recomputed when any of their observable/computed dependencies change. Knockout will not see a simple property update like you are doing.

Comment: so How can I write that on my code? Would be good if I got a better explanation in writing since I am pretty new to it

Comment: i tried making it like this self.Available = ko.observable(money.Available);
and then made self.Available() == '9999-12-10' etc 
But did not work

Comment: Only create the observable once. Can you post your updated code?